# Hypothesis to be proven - beta distributions and integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, binomial-theorem

I am interested in the following formula:
$$f_{2m+1}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^m {2m+1\choose i}x^{2m+1-i}(1-x)^i$$
This is half of the binomial representation of $1=(x+1-x)^k$ for $k=2m+1$.*

I treat the term above as a function. Intuitively:
$\int_0^1 f_{k}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\text{ for any }k=2m+1.$

Now, what is $\int_0^1 x f_k(x)?$

My hypothesis (based on results for small $k$) is that:
$$\int_0^1 x f_k(x)=\frac{\frac{3}{2}(k+1)+1}{4(k+2)}=\frac{3m+4}{8m+12.}$$

However, I don't know how to prove it in a clean manner.

*I chose $k$ odd specifically to have symmetric halves and not worry about the middle element. Also, the functions $x^k(1-x)^j$ are associated with some beta distributions, if it is of any help.

Comment: Note that $f_{2m+1}(x)=P(U^{2m+1}_{(m+1)}>x)$ where $U^{2m+1}_{(m+1)}$ is the median of a uniform i.i.d. sample of size $2m+1$, thus, $$\int_0^1f_{2m+1}(x)dx=E(U^{2m+1}_{(m+1)})$$ and $$\int_0^1xf_{2m+1}(x)dx=\int_0^1xP(U^{2m+1}_{(m+1)}>x)dx=\tfrac12E((U^{2m+1}_{(m+1)})^2)$$ Now, the distribution of $U^{2m+1}_{(m+1)}$ is Beta$(m+1,m+1)$ hence $$E(U^{2m+1}_{(m+1)})=\int_0^1B(m+1,m+1)u^{m+1}(1-u)^mdu=\frac{B(m+1,m+1)}{B(m+2,m+1)}=\frac{m+1}{2m+2}=\frac12$$ and $$E((U^{2m+1}_{(m+1)})^2)=\int_0^1B(m+1,m+1)u^{m+2}(1-u)^mdu=\frac{B(m+1,m+1)}{B(m+3,m+1)}=\frac{(m+2)(m+1)}{(2m+2)(2m+3)}$$ hence...

Comment: $$\int_0^1f_{2m+1}(x)dx=\frac12$$ and $$\int_0^1xf_{2m+1}(x)dx=\frac{m+2}{4(2m+3)}$$

Comment: Using order statistics is a great idea! The last formula does not work (e.g. for $m=0$ we have $\int_0^1x^2=1/3,$ while your formula suggests $1/6$. But apart from that I am quite sure the general idea of using uniform samples is *the* way to prove the result in a beautiful fashion. Will check it and thanks a lot! Also, if you post the tip as an answer, I will give you credit :)

Comment: Ok, I found a mistake. In fact, when we integrate by parts:$$\int_0^1xP(U_{m+1}^{2m+1}>x)=\frac{1}{2}-E((U_{m+1}^{2m+1})^2).$$
All other things are correct, but in the end we have:
$$\int_0^1 xf_{2m+1}(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{m+2}{4(2m+3)}=\frac{3m+4}{8m+12}$$

Comment: The "integration by parts" formula in your last comment cannot be true. Anyway, at this point I suggest you post a full answer, so that everybody can check its details, missing one-halves and the like.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I posted the answer (with a sign switch). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think now I figured out all the details. 
The suggestion in the comment was most helpful, only the sign was opposite. In fact:$$f_{2m+1}(x)=P(U_{m+1}^{2m+1}< x)=P(U_{m+1}^{2m+1}\leq x),$$
where $U_{m+1}^{2m+1}$ is an $m+1$-st order statistic of a uniform sample of size $2m+1.$
Since the distribution of $U_{m+1}^{2m+1}$ is $Beta(m+1,m+1)$, then we can use known results. Integrating by parts (with $F_{Beta}, f_{Beta}$ denoting the cdf and pdf of beta distribution), we get:
$$\int_0^1xF_{Beta}(x)dx=\left .\left(\frac{x^2}{2}F_{Beta}(x)\right)\right|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{2}f_{Beta}(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}E(u_{m+1}^{2m+1})^2$$

Since the second moment of beta distribution is:
$$E(U_{m+1}^{2m+1})^2=\frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{(2m+3)(2m+2)}=\frac{m+2}{2(2m+3)}.$$
Then:
$$\int_0^1 xf_{2m+1}(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{m+2}{4(2m+3)}=\frac{3m+4}{8m+12}.$$